# Azure Container registry Repository Go Client unable to fetch attribute

Tags: azure, docker, go, azure-container-registry, container-registry

I am unable to fetch attributes for a particular container repository of Azure Container registry.

I have also tried weird combinations to run this.

Attempt 1

```
loginURI := "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + resourceGroupName + "/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/" + registryName + ".azurecr.io"
```

> Attempt 1 error message

```
azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="MissingApiVersionParameter" Message="The api-version query parameter (?api-version=) is required for all requests."
```

Attempt 2

```
loginURI := "https://" + registryName + ".azurecr.io/acr/v1/hello-world"
```

Attempt 3

```
loginURI := "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + resourceGroupName + "/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/" + registryName + ".azurecr.io?api-version=2019-08-15-preview"
```

> Attempt 3 error message

```
2020/04/28 13:33:45 Error while fetching location list, containerregistry.RepositoryClient#GetAttributes: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=400 -- Original Error: autorest/
azure: Service returned an error. Status=400 Code="NoRegisteredProviderFound" Message="No registered resource provider found for location 'westus' and API version '2019-08-15-previ
ew/acr/v1/hello-world?api-version=2019-08-15-preview' for type 'registries'. The supported api-versions are '2016-06-27-preview, 2017-03-01, 2017-10-01, 2019-05-01, 2019-12-01-prev
iew, 2017-06-01-preview'. The supported locations are 'westus, eastus, southcentralus, westeurope, northeurope, uksouth, ukwest, australiaeast, australiasoutheast, centralindia, ko
reacentral, francecentral, southafricanorth, uaenorth, eastasia, japaneast, japanwest, southeastasia, southindia, brazilsouth, canadaeast, canadacentral, centralus, eastus2, northc
entralus, westcentralus, westus2, switzerlandnorth'."
```

But still no luck while fetching attributes

Can anyone suggest the correct me away if I am doing something wrong here?
Is this the correct way of providing loginURI for Container repository Client?
Do we need to specify ApiVersion for the same, if yes then how?
Is there any examples available for ACR's Repository so I can refer it.

Sample code can be found down here

Go version
go1.14.2 windows/amd64

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/profiles/preview/preview/containerregistry/runtime/containerregistry"
    "github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/services/resources/mgmt/2015-11-01/subscriptions"
    "github.com/Azure/go-autorest/autorest/azure/auth"
    "log"
    "os"
)
func main() {
    subscriptionId := ""
    clientId := ""
    clientSecret := ""
    tenantId := ""
    resourceGroupName := ""
    registryName := "test"
        repositoryName := "hello-world"
    err := os.Setenv("AZURE_CLIENT_ID", clientId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while setting env variable, %v ", err)
    }
    err = os.Setenv("AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET", clientSecret)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while setting env variable, %v ", err)

    }
    err = os.Setenv("AZURE_TENANT_ID", tenantId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while setting env variable, %v ", err)

    }
    err = os.Setenv("AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID", subscriptionId)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while setting env variable, %v ", err)
    }
    authorizer, err := auth.NewAuthorizerFromEnvironment()
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while creating an new authentication, %v ", err)

    }
    loginURI := "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscriptionId + "/resourceGroups/" + resourceGroupName + "/providers/Microsoft.ContainerRegistry/registries/"
    subscriptionsClient := containerregistry.NewRepositoryClient(loginURI)
    subscriptionsClient.Authorizer = authorizer
    attributes, err2 := subscriptionsClient.GetAttributes(context.Background(), registryName+ "/"+ repositoryName)
    if err2 != nil {
        log.Printf("Error while fetching attributes, %v ", err)
    }
    fmt.Print(attributes)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/8654

All you have to do is, use AZURE credentials like this,

```
authorizer, err := auth.NewAuthorizerFromEnvironment()
containerRegistryClient := containerregistry.NewRegistriesClient(credential.SubscriptionId)
containerRegistryClient.Authorizer = authorizer
containerRegistryCredential, err := containerRegistryClient.ListCredentials(context.Background(), resourceGroupName, registryName)
```

After that you will receive credentials to access the container repository, now use basic authorizer to authenticate,

```
basicAuthorizer := autorest.NewBasicAuthorizer(<userName>, <password>)
tagClient := repository.NewTagClient("https://" + <loginServer>)
tagClient.Authorizer = basicAuthorizer
repositoryTagDetails, err := tagClient.GetList(context.Background(), <repositoryName>, "", nil, "", "")
```

That's it!

Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the imports?

Comment: Can you add a full code example please?